# The Red House: Was the house and the insipid conversation scripted?

Tags: better-call-saul

In Hit and Run S6 E4 we discover that Gus is paying a decoy couple to live in a house where they have cordial but limited interactions with Fring's army of soldiers and spies. The conversation about neighbors violating association codes sounds as if it was rehearsed, like they were supposed to go on a bike ride that day, encounter the red house (tomato red) and then discuss it. It almost seems like they were supposed to completely ignore Gus' men until one asks for a glass of ice tea, almost a dramatic moment in an otherwise incredibly insipid scene.

So is it indeed possible that Fring's people literally provide the couple with a daily agenda?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. As Mike tells Gus, the team are already stretched thin. They're trying to keep a 24/7 watch for Lalo; a smart, driven, vicious opponent who could show up anywhere, at any time.

They're monitoring camera feeds, researching random vehicles that happen to drive behind Gus for three blocks, and trying to find bodyguards with sufficient kitchen experience to meet the exacting standards at Los Pollos Hermanos. No-one in this team has time or reason to script neighbourhood-related conversations for the cover couple.

If the conversation sounds really boring and suburban, it's because this couple really are really boring and suburban. Sure, they're being paid by a drug lord to let a tactical team use their home as a secret safe-house, but they probably don't know about the drug lord part. They're getting paid to do nothing, so that someone important is protected. As such, they've got plenty of spare time to contemplate the aesthetic politics of their local homeowners associations.

Comment: they may not know specifically about the drug lord part but they sure know something is going on. also, that body double for Gus -- I wonder if he has Gus' dentist, if u know what i mean.